# C++ Typedef inside classes using private members

Tags: c++, class, oop, typedef

I tried to customize some types inside a class by using private members, which are used to set the size of customized containers. But I received:

```
error: ‘CoverMatrix’ does not name a type
error: ‘Board’ does not name a type
```

How do I properly manipulate it?

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>


class SudokuBoard
{
private:
    Board _board_data;
    int _BOX_SIZE;
    int _BOARD_SIZE;
    const int _MAX_VALUE = _BOARD_SIZE;
    const int _NUM_CONSTRAINTS = 4;
    
public:
    template <class T, int ROW, int COL>
    using Matrix = std::array<std::array<T, COL>, ROW>;
    typedef CoverMatrix Matrix<int, _BOARD_SIZE * _BOARD_SIZE * _MAX_VALUE, _BOARD_SIZE * _BOARD_SIZE * _NUM_CONSTRAINTS>;
    typedef Board       Matrix<int, _BOARD_SIZE, _BOARD_SIZE>;

    SudokuBoard(const std::string& filename);

    void set_board_data(int row, int col, int num) { _board_data[row][col] = num; }
    int get_board_data(int row, int col) const { return _board_data[row][col]; }
    Board get_board_data() const { return _board_data; }
    int at(int row, int col) const { return _board_data[row][col]; }
    
    // Prints the Sudoku board
    friend void print_board(const SudokuBoard& board);
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &out, const SudokuBoard& board);

    int indexInCoverMatrix(int row, int col, int num);
    int createBoxConstraints(CoverMatrix coverMatrix, int header);
    int createColumnConstraints(CoverMatrix coverMatrix, int header);
    int createRowConstraints(CoverMatrix coverMatrix, int header);
    int createCellConstraints(CoverMatrix coverMatrix, int header);
    void createCoverMatrix(CoverMatrix coverMatrix);
    void convertToCoverMatrix(Board board, CoverMatrix coverMatrix);
};
```

Comment: Do note that none of `int _BOX_SIZE;`, `int _BOARD_SIZE;`, `const int _MAX_VALUE = _BOARD_SIZE;`, `const int _NUM_CONSTRAINTS = 4;` can be used in the template parameters as they are not compile time constants.

Comment: Please check the correct [`typedef` syntax](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef).

Comment: You did not state the C++ version you are using but you might be interested in the `using` keyword. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias

Comment: You already use `using` for `Matrix`, why not extend it for `CoverMatrix`/`Board`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already use `using` correctly to set up the `Matrix` type. You really should just keep doing that with the other types too:

```
using CoverMatrix = Matrix<int, _BOARD_SIZE* _BOARD_SIZE* _MAX_VALUE, _BOARD_SIZE* _BOARD_SIZE* _NUM_CONSTRAINTS>;
using Board       = Matrix<int, _BOARD_SIZE, _BOARD_SIZE>;
```

But if you for some reason insist on mixing `using` and `typedef`, then the correct syntax is:

```
typedef Matrix<int, _BOARD_SIZE* _BOARD_SIZE* _MAX_VALUE, _BOARD_SIZE* _BOARD_SIZE* _NUM_CONSTRAINTS> CoverMatrix;
typedef Matrix<int, _BOARD_SIZE, _BOARD_SIZE> Board;
```

In other words:

```
using identifier = type;
typedef type identifier;
```

Also, do note that as @NathanOliver pointed out, your private `int` members are not compile time constants. So after you fix the `typedef` syntax the code still won't work - but you can put that in a new question if you need help with that. StackOverflow prefers only one topic per question.